# Generate additional random number from array of 20 integers

Tags: java, arrays, random, methods

I am having trouble with this, I need to generate an additional single random number that has the same 1-10 span. I already have the code for the random generator that produces my 20 integer array of random numbers but how do I generate a single random number in the same span within the same method. This is what I have so far and it keeps giving me random number 0: from my 20 integer array. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
class Main{
 public static final Random RND_GEN = new Random();
   public int[] createNum(int[] randomNumbers) {
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
        randomNumbers[i] = RND_GEN.nextInt(10) + 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1 ; i++){
    randomNumbers[i] = RND_GEN.nextInt(10) + 1;

    }

    return randomNumbers;
}

public void printNum(int[] randomNumbers){
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Number " + i + " : " + randomNumbers[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
    System.out.println("Single # is: "+randomNumbers[i]); 
}
}
public void searchArray(int[] randomNumbers, int numSearch) {
int count = 0;

for (int i : randomNumbers) {
    if (i == numSearch) {
        count++;
    }
}
if (count == 0) {
    System.out.println("Number # " + numSearch + " was not found!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Number #" + numSearch + " occurred " + count + "              times.");
}
}





public void run() {
    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 1;
    do {
        int[] numbers = new int[20];
        numbers = createNum(numbers);
        printNum(numbers);

        System.out.print("Restart Program?, Enter 1 for YES, 2 for NO: ");
        x = inputReader.nextInt();
    } while (x == 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main go = new Main();
    go.run();
}
}
```

Comment: @robotlos I have been putting nothing but effort in to get to this point, maybe my brain is fried from staring at this problem all day but I am lost, there should be no recourse for trying to seek the help of others who are way more talented at I when it comes to this stuff

Comment: @kidbone222, going through your questions, most (if not all) of the things you've asked can be answered with a quick Google search. There's a difference between asking for help and asking someone to do your assignment.

Comment: @Ceelos, I'm not asking anyone to do my HW, the problem is you can google search all day but if you dont understand what your looking at then it becomes a constant struggle. I learn best by seeing the examples of what to do when explained by gentlemen like you guys who understand what the code is doing and needs to do

Comment: @Ceelos - It's hard to see how a Google search would have helped with this problem. It wasn't a problem of how to generate random numbers; it was a logic issue with the looping structure of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop in `printNum()` looks suspicious:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
    System.out.println("Single # is: "+randomNumbers[i]); 
}
```

It will always print the first element of `randomNumbers`. It's not clear what you want, but if I had to guess it would be:

```
int i = RND_GEN.nextInt(randomNumbers.length);
System.out.println("Single # is: " + randomNumbers[i]);
```

which will print some random element of `randomNumbers`. Or perhaps:

```
int i = 1 + RND_GEN.nextInt(10);
System.out.println("Single # is: " + i);
```

which will print an independent random number between 1 and 10 (inclusive).

P.S. You have another one of those suspicious loops earlier in your code in `createNum()` as well. However, that one seems harmless in that it just assigns a second random number to `randomNumbers[0]`.

Comment: Thats the thing the number does not have to come from the previously generated array of random numbers, it only has to been a number from 1-10. And the loop that I have will only print a number that is already in the first array of 20 integers@ Ted Hopp

Comment: @kidbone222 - Well, the loop will print the first element of `randomNumbers`. Perhaps what you want is `System.out.println("Single # is: " + (RND_GEN.nextInt(10) + 1));`.

Comment: Is there a way to rewrite the loop so that it doesn't print out the first element of randomNumbers and prints out a random number? @Ted Hopp

Comment: @kidbone222 - Since the loop executes exactly once, why have a loop at all? Just print out a random number (as I suggested in the edit to my answer).

Comment: Thank you @Ted Hopp, I was so stuck in using another loop since that was how I generated the first numbers that I couldnt see how that would work

Comment: I am knocking on the door now, but am getting a funky return. Rather than counting the single random number, it is counting a random number from within the 20 integer array. I'm confused as to why it is not counting the number of times the single random appears within the array. I am going to answer the original question with my updated code so you can see what Im talking about @Ted Hopp

Comment: @kidbone222 - The `"Single # ..."` output prints a different random number than the one that you are using in the call to `searchArray()`. Perhaps that explains the behavior?

Comment: so would it be necessary to declare an entirely different method to create the single random number and then call that method to the searchArray()? @Ted Hopp

Comment: @kidbone222 - No, you just have to save the single random number as you do now in `run()` and  print it there instead of in `printNum()` (or, alternatively, pass it to `printNum()` as a second argument to be printed there).

Comment: Oh, so shift the single random number print to within the searchArray(), I have done this and it still only counts any random number within the array @Ted Hopp

Comment: @kidbone222 - This discussion has morphed into a completely different problem than where you started. It's very hard for me to understand exactly what's going on. I suggest that you post your current code in a new question and explain what behavior you expect, what you are getting, and how you've tried to reconcile the two.